# UPDATE and count up column "downloaded" by +1 from a session

Tags: php, mysql, session, cart

How do I increment the "downloaded" field for images in my cart session after I have clicked the "BUY" button?

Do I have to use `UPDATE myTable SET downloaded= +1`?

[image]

```php
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['product'])) {
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
} 

if (isset($_GET['product'])) {    
    if (!in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])) {
        $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
    }    
    header("location: kurv.php");       
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {    
    foreach ($_SESSION['product'] as $key => $val) { 
        if ($val == $_GET['delete']) {
            unset($_SESSION['product'][$key]);
        }
    }       
}    

$product = array();
$crud = new crud($con);

foreach ($_SESSION['product'] as $item) {
    $product[] = $crud->select_id('stockworld_product', 'id', $item)->fetch_object();
}    

?><form action="" method="POST"><?php
    foreach($product as $item):
        if(!$item)continue;

        ?><div style="width: 100%; height: 80px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
            <div style="margin-left: 20px; float: left; ">                
                <h1 class="fontclass3b"><?php echo $item->title; ?></h1><br>
                <h1 class="fontclass2b">af </h1> 
                <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 500; color: #343434;">
                    <?php echo $item->photograph; ?>
                </h1>            
            </div>
            <div style="margin-right: 20px; float: right; line-height: 80px; ">
                <a href="kurv.php?delete=<?php echo $item->id; ?>"  id="fjern">Fjern</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach;?>

    <hr id="hr2" noshade>

    <button type="submit" id="add_to_basket" style="width: 30% !important;">Godkend</button>     

</form>
```

Comment: with an update query - the problem would be ?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem would be

Comment: the problem i see is no code to achive the desired result

Comment: @Dagon Time for us to get ourselves one of those fancy *Buy me a beer* button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE myTable SET downloaded = downloaded + 1 WHERE id = [your row id];

Comment: but how do I get the row id ?

Comment: From the data posted by your form: `<input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to update.

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `downloads`=`downloads`+1 WHERE ????
```

Comment: how and where exactly do I have to write it in there ?